# Component Dependency Failed Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

I have memory limit of 5G, still memory get exhausted and getting component dependency failed as attached screenshot.[image: 3]

Comment: are you upgrading? or is it a fresh install?

Comment: It's fresh install

Comment: this could be a composer.json issue

Comment: @DeepSwaroopSachan Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Gem No, so I moved my code to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands:

```
composer install --no-dev
```

OR

```
composer update --no-dev
```

It should fix your issue.